# How to mock functions of a function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm using `simple-git` in my script like this:

```
import simpleGit from 'simple-git'
const git = simpleGit()

const foo = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const tags: string = await git.tag({
    '--list': null,
    '--format': '%(objectname:short)'
  })
}
```

In my tests I need to mock out the git calls, which I'm doing this way:

```
jest.mock('simple-git', () => ({
  tag: () => jest.fn()
}))
```

But this is failing. I guess, I have to take care of `const git = simpleGit()`

Comment: The mockImplementation parameter is a factory function that returns the test double. You're trying to replace a function, the factory provides an object. So I guess when you say "failing" (include the _output_ in a [mre]) you're being told it's not callable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `simple-git` is installed via `node_module` (which I assume it is) you only need to create a directory called `__mocks__` at the root of your project anything placed there is automatically mocked in your case you need to create a  file called `simple-git.js`

```
.
├── __mocks__
│   └── simple-git.js
├── node_modules
```

Reference: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules